# Wordpress query. Correctly referencing the excerpt for a page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Stuck with a Wordpress query...
It's proably obvious what i'm trying to do.... But one line i just can't work out, and can't find any online info about it...

I've marked the excerpt line of code which i believe is causing the problems. What would be the correct reference for the excerpt?

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 2,
'post_type' => 'page',
'meta_key' => 'front_page_feature',
'meta_value' => '1'
));

if($posts)
{
echo '<ul>';

foreach($posts as $post)
{
    echo '<li><article><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '"><h2>' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</h2>';
    $excerpt = get_post_excerpt($post->ID); <<<<<<<<<<<<----- HERE
    if (strlen($excerpt) > 135) {
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 135) . '...';
            }
echo '<p>'. $excerpt .'</p>';
    echo '</a></article></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but isn´t the $post variable in the foreach an object?
If so you could do `$post->post_excerpt;`

**EDIT:** 
After looking more into it I´ve found that this won´t work.
But you can easily adjust your script to work the way you want it to.

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); 

    if (strlen($excerpt) > 135) {
       $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 135) . '...';
    }

    printf(
        '<li><article><a href="%s"><h2>%s</h2><p>%s</p></a></article></li>', 
        get_permalink(), 
        get_the_title(),
        $excerpt
    );
}
```

I´ve not tested it, but it should work.

In the example on the [get_post page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) you can see how the setup_postdata is used.

Also note, that it says on the [get_the_excerpt page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) that the parameter of the function is deprecated.